# What can be fixed when iOS Springboard crashes constantly?

Tags: ipad, icloud, springboard

The Springboard on my Late 2018 iPad Pro and now iPhone (as of the last month), crashes between every 20 minutes to 3 hours. I run iOS 13.2.3

The screen goes black, the spinning wheel appears, continues for about 6 seconds and then the Home screen reappears. Any app that I launch reloads.

I've have the same case number with multiple Apple Senior Advisors since February and they simply can't figure it out. They have already replaced the iPad as a possible solution. They sent in my log files from an Apple profile to the iCloud team. They've had the log files for 2 months and have never replied. Obviously they're lost too.

I've done every normal troubleshooting step under the sun, resetting to factory settings, putting it in recovery mode from iTunes and rebuilding the iPad from scratch, with no iCloud restore. I even signed in with a different, new Apple ID to test that. No joy, it still crashes.

I believe I've narrowed down the cause: corrupted iCloud library folders/files because iCloud on a Mac syncs to an iOS device.

So what's the best way to replace and re-build those? Recovery mode on my iMac and Macbook? A Terminal command?

I can't use my iPad Pro as a functional daily driver when it keeps crashing when working.  I moved (essentially deleted) several iCloud library folders on my Macbook and my iPad continues to crash.

What steps can be done to isolate or fix this crashing?

Comment: How did you find this out? Was it because it was restarting only when you used or app switch to safari?

Comment: Hi CyberMew: I figured it out because it would consistently crash when I added a website from Safari as a "add to home screen" app. From there, I realized I had duplicated the error. That got me thinking it had to be connected to Safari websites. From there, I dug into the Safari settings and got pretty lucky. Thankfully.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

The corrupt data lived in Safari's History and Website Data. It was transferring the data between devices through my Apple ID.

I went to settings on my iPad, Safari, "Clear History and Website Data."